# Append values to dictionary based on keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains multiple people's ID and an integer value (win total) like this:

```
{12345: 2, 23456: 10}
```

There are only 2 people in it currently for testing, but there will be a lot.

I have another dictionary in the same format with a different integer value (total games) like this:

```
{12345: 10, 23456: 20}
```

I need to create a third dictionary that stores win percentage like this (taking value from 1st dictionary and dividing by second dictionary):

`{12345: .200, 23456: .500}`  *keeping raw percentage

**-OR-**

`{12345: 20, 23456: 50}`  *multiply by 100 to get integer value (if that is only way I can do it)

This needs to be done for all players in the dictionary.  There should be a matching pair in each dictionary for every person.

Can someone help?  I have scoured these forums for days and can't find a good way to do it.

Comment: I confess it worries me a little that you're storing these values in independent dicts, and then dividing them later. Presumably if someone has a *win total* he must also have a *total games*. You should store them all in the same data structure so you don't have two (or three) key lookups for each player. I would create a `Player` class, but if OOP is not to your liking, perhaps just a dict of [`namedtuple('wins', 'games')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 1):

Why not compute the win percentage for each person on the fly? It'd be easier and more effective (and in keeping with good data storage principles) than keeping a third dictionary.

Something like:

```
def win_percentage(id):
    if id in total_games and id in num_wins and total_games[id] > 0:
        return num_wins[id] / float(total_games[id])
    else:
        return 0 # or raise an exception, whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
{ key: wins[key]/games[key] for key in wins.keys()
                            if key in games and games[key]>0
}
```

where `wins` and `games` -- your source dictionaries. This will create result values only for keys presented in both dictionaries.

Comment: This will return zero for everyone unless you convert the numerator or denominator to a `float()`.

Comment: @ChristianTernus No, this is clearly Python3, so it will convert to float implicitly. In Python2 you can `from __future__ import division`. See [PEP-238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Comment: @kojiro That's excellent! Another tool in my toolbox -- thank you.

Comment: Yes, I ment Python3. And I've just added extra check for zero denominator, just in case :)

Comment: @kojiro What makes it clear that this is Python3? Does 2 not support dict-comprehensions?

Comment: @Edward for the most part, no, although 2.7 does, but then you just need the `from __future__…` I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a new dictionary with the percentages.

The cases where total games is zero or a people's entry is missing the games dictionary are handled by setting the percentage to 0.

```
wins={12345: 2, 23456: 10}
games={12345: 10, 23456: 20}

percentage={}
for key, value in wins.iteritems():
    try :
       percentage[key]=wins[key]*1.0/games[key]*1.0
    except KeyError :
       percentage[key]=0
    except ZeroDivisionError :
       percentage[key]=0
```

Comment: You can save some time with a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or with `percentage.setdefault(key,0)` instead of the `KeyError` check.

Comment: @kojiro: The "easier to ask forgiveness then permission" style shown in this answer can be faster in some cases (though I think not this one, since you're not doing any updating of existing percentages). Python exceptions aren't orders of magnitude slower than other control structures (like exceptions are in some other languages), so it's perfectly fine to use them to deal with uncommon but not truly "exceptional" situations. Heck, the implementation of every `for` loop involves throwing a `StopIteration` exception to mark its end!

Comment: @Blckknght Except that if you use exceptions as signals sometimes you accidentally hide real errors, as is the case here. You should clearly never have a case where a key exist for `wins` but not for `games`. (How can you win a game you've never played?)